# zparseopts with associative array in older version of zsh

Tags: zsh

I am confused by the differing behavior of `zparseopts` in two different versions of zsh. Basically I am trying to set a list of default option values in an associative array and overwrite these defaults with any options specified on the command line. The below code works well for zsh 5.0.6 but behaves oddly for 4.3.6-- specifically, in zsh 4.3.6, my whole array of defaults is overwritten if a single key is overwritten.

#### myscript

```
typeset -A opts
opts=(
--opt1 a
--opt2 b
)

zparseopts -A opts -K -- -opt1: -opt2:
echo ${(k)opts}
```

#### Running the script

```
$ myscript 
--opt1 --opt2  # both zsh 4.3.6 and 5.0.6

$ myscript --opt1 x
--opt1 --opt2  # zsh 5.0.6; element of array is replaced
--opt1         # zsh 4.3.6; adding an element overwrites the whole array, no more opt2
```

This behavior is confusing because 4.3.6 and 5.0.6 have identical entries for the `-K` option to `zparseopts`:

> -K  With  this  option,  the  arrays  specified  with  the -a and -A
>        options and with the `=array' forms are kept unchanged when none
>        of  the  specs  for  them  is  used.   This allows assignment of
>        default values to them before calling zparseopts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace the last line of your script with `echo ${(kv)opts}`. Running with 4.3.6 and 5.0.6 should show that 4.3.6 interprets `-K` to reset `opts` if *any* options are given, while `5.0.6` only resets `opts[--opt1]` when `--opt1` is used (leaving `--opt2` or any other entry alone).

(Note this appeared to change sometime between 5.0.2 and 5.0.6; you might want to ask on the zsh-workers mailing list to confirm.)=